# Multiplication Map of Exterior Powers Induces Isomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, exterior-algebra

This is Vakil 13.5 G, self-study. I have already spent three hours trying to solve the problem and research the answer, and would consequently like a complete answer. I have seen 3 different answers in three different solution guides to Hartshorne's comparable exercise 2.5.16, and all of them were seemingly different, and all claimed everything was obvious.

We are given a locally free sheaf $\mathcal F$ of rank $n$, and asked to describe a map

$$\bigwedge\nolimits^r \mathcal F \times \bigwedge\nolimits^{n - r} \mathcal F \to \bigwedge\nolimits^n \mathcal F$$

inducing an isomorphism

$$\bigwedge\nolimits^r \mathcal F \to \Big(\bigwedge\nolimits^{n - r} \mathcal F\Big)^* \otimes \bigwedge\nolimits^n \mathcal F$$

This topic really seems to assume you have taken Differential Geometry before, which I have not. If I had to guess, I would say the map on an open set on which $\mathcal F$ is free is

$$(e_1 \wedge ... \wedge e_r, e_{r + 1}\wedge ... \wedge e_n) \mapsto (e_1 \wedge ... \wedge e_r \wedge e_{r + 1}\wedge ... \wedge e_n)$$

if the $e_i$ form a basis for $\mathcal F$ locally, but I am not actually sure what I am really saying here. I feel I am just writing down expressions that look correct and not truly grasping what is happening.

Even if my "guess" is correct, I have no idea how this induces the isomorphism asked of us.

Comment: Potential duplicate of [External power of locally free sheaves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3637264/external-power-of-locally-free-sheaves/3639475#3639475)

Comment: @KReiser This is part d). I am asking about part b).