# Vector Bundles：differential geometry vs algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

I am in trouble about the vector bundle part in the Friedman's book: *Algebraic Surfaces and Holomorphic Vector Bundle*, I know what is a vector bundle(or a fibre bundle) in the differential geometry, but it seems that vector bundles in the algebraic geometry are something different, so who can tell me what is connection or difference between the two kinds of vector bundles, how to understand vector bundles in the algebraic geometry?

Comment: In Hartshorne there is an exercise relating locally free sheaf and vector bundle (II 5.18)

Comment: I believe a superior source to Hartshorne is Gortz and Wedhorn's "Algebraic Geometry I", chapter 11.

Comment: If $M$ is a smooth manifold and $\mathcal{O}_M$ is the sheaf of real-valued smooth functions on $M$, there is an equivalence between the categories of smooth vector bundles over $M$ and that of locally finite free $\mathcal{O}_M$-modules. A proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4627208/394668). The formal counterpart in schemes is also true, see Proposition 11.7 from Görtz, Wedhorn, *Algebraic Geometry I: Schemes*, 2nd ed.

Answer (score 4):

They're the same thing; it's just that sometimes in algebraic geometry instead of talking about a vector bundle $E \xrightarrow{\pi} X$ explicitly, we talk about the sheaf $\mathscr{E}$ that associates to an open set $U \subset X$ the set of all sections $s : U \to E$ of $X$, and call this the "vector bundle."  The sheaves that arise in such a way are precisely the locally free sheaves on $X$.

Comment: Look at this question:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218837/short-exact-sequence-of-holomorphic-vector-bundles-splits-but-not-holomorphicall/218899#218899 it seems that we can not get the similar version in the differential geometry.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  That question is about splittings.  Can you elaborate on what you want to know?

Comment: Splitting is one of difference between these two kinds of vector bundles, I want to see more difference, how does the  vector bundles in the algebraic geometry different from the differential geometry, for example, the splittings.

Comment: That's not because vector bundles in algebraic geometry are somehow different gadgets from vector bundles in differential geometry.  It's analogous to how $f(x) = x^2$ has an inverse function in the differential setting but not the algebraic one, because $g(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is smooth but not a polynomial.  You have different behavior in different categories, but it's not because $x^2$ in the differential category is somehow different from $x^2$ in the algebraic category.

Comment: I want to see more phenomenon about the difference of vector bundles, except the splittings.